# Tile System and Tile Drawing

Tags: c#, xna

I'm triyng to make an Automated type tile system to draw my int[,] tileMap according to my Texture Atlas but when i run the code i get the entire thing sideways and the textures don't appear, the only way i know it's sideways is because the "Color color" for drawing the textures are different then the ClearScreen's color.

## Tile Sorting Class:

```
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public int Columns { get; set; }
    public int totalTiles;
    public int _tileWidth;
    public int _tileHeight;
    public int[] tiles;
    public int[,] tileMap = new int[,] {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
            {0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}
    };

    public Tile(Texture2D texture, int tileWidth, int tileHeight)
    {
        _tileWidth = tileWidth;
        _tileHeight = tileHeight;
        Texture = texture;
        totalTiles = Rows * Columns;

    }


    public void Update() {

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Vector2 location)
    {

        for (int row = 0; row < tileMap.GetLength(1); row++) {

            for (int col = 0; col < tileMap.GetLength(0); col++) {

                switch (tileMap[row, col]) {
                    case 0:
                        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle(row * _tileWidth, col * _tileHeight, _tileWidth, _tileHeight), new Rectangle(1 * _tileWidth, 1 * _tileHeight, _tileWidth, _tileHeight), Color.Transparent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle(row * _tileWidth, col * _tileHeight, _tileWidth, _tileHeight), new Rectangle(2 * _tileWidth, 2 * _tileHeight, _tileWidth, _tileHeight), Color.Transparent);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
```

## The Main Class

```
public class Main : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game {
    // Basic code for drawing.
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Tile test;
    Texture2D texturePack;

    public Main() {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }


    protected override void Initialize() {

        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent() {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        texturePack = Content.Load<Texture2D>("AxiomTileSheet");
        test = new Tile(texturePack, 8, 8);
    }


    protected override void UnloadContent() {
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        test.Draw(spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this

```
switch (tileMap[row, col])
```

should be

```
switch (tileMap[col, row])
```

as you use col for you x values and row for y.

You also need to switch this in your rectangle calculations.

Another hint for performance based on my experience  (as Andrew mentioned this may not be worthwhile in every case) instead of creating new rectangles every frame define 2 rectangles in you Tile class and just change the x and y values every frame

floAr

EDIT: Color Problem=============================

You can completly get rid of the switch case construct by using

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
    for (int row = 0; row < tileMap.GetLength(1); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < tileMap.GetLength(0); col++)
            {
                        spriteBatch.Draw(_texture, new Rectangle(row * _tW, col * _tH, _tW, _tH), new Rectangle(tileMap[row, col] * _tW, tileMap[row, col] * _tH, _tW, _tH), Color.White);
            }
        }
        }
```

Note: _tH=_tileHeight, _tW=_tileWidth
I tested this out and it worked like a charm for me ;) 
If you want to keep the switch case make sure you set Color.White as your tinting color (last spritebatch parameter). And you need to correct the values of the switch case, as you use 0 and 2 in your map definition, but 0 and 1 in your switch case. Expanding the cases up to 3 (as it seems you have 4 tiles by now) also worked for me.

So I think your issue was based on the wrong color and a typo in the case structure.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That is not a worthwhile optimisation. `Rectangle` is a value-type. Creating one is a *very* cheap operation. (Reference types are the expensive ones, due to garbage creation.)

Comment: Ok thanks for your input. I edited the answer to reflect it. This tip was given on personal experience. In an universtiy project some years ago this gave us about 5 FPS more, but we also had a lot of these draw calls.

Comment: It can theoretically improve performance by a tiny amount ([here is an interesting case I was investigating once](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/604/why-does-farseer-2-x-store-temporaries-as-members-and-not-on-the-stack-net)). However it is very much a *micro*-optimisation. Best avoided, if possible - and should only be done with appropriate profiling and need. Not good general advice - which is why I jumped on it. (Whereas the reference-type case is an acceptable systemic optimisation - where you are trying to avoid allocating anywhere, to avoid an expensive collection.)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed info and for the clarification :)

Comment: Just a quick question, any idea on why the drawing only shows the Color.Colors of each case instead of the source texture?

Comment: Texture is reserved by XNA, this is why it is shown in blue. Try to rename it to reflect your variable or try using this.Texture. Also you may try to fiddle with Color.White instead of Color.Transparent

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately neither of those fixes work. I still get the same error, I've tried creating different solutions with the same exact error. If you want my project files to try to fix it I can post them for you, but I can't seem to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Hmm i am not able to reproduce the error now, but it "should" work if you replace every occurrence of Texture with "_texture" for example.

Comment: There's no error, it's just that it won't draw my textures, even simply drawing the texture it's just black.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?d5092l7bkeiarbx
Link to the Solution, tell me if you can get it working, if not oh well.

Comment: I just downloaded it and was able to fix the error. I edited the solution into the main answer. Keep going with XNA ;) floAr